Why can't I insert the URL of an image off google into this ViLT?
I am trying to use this ViLT:
from transformers import ViltProcessor, ViltForQuestionAnswering
import requests
from PIL import Image

# prepare image + question
url = "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
text = "How many cats are there?"

processor = ViltProcessor.from_pretrained("dandelin/vilt-b32-finetuned-vqa")
model = ViltForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("dandelin/vilt-b32-finetuned-vqa")

# prepare inputs
encoding = processor(image, text, return_tensors="pt")

# forward pass
outputs = model(**encoding)
logits = outputs.logits
idx = logits.argmax(-1).item()
print("Predicted answer:", model.config.id2label[idx])

but when I try to input another image an error pops up: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ce8e20ac540>
I am quite new to this so sorry if I am missing something very obvious.
